# Client is not connected to the server

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, socket.io-client

I am using yiicod/yii-socketio for server socket and for client we use socket.io-client. On server side things are successfully done but on client side i am facing conenction issue from client to server.

But when i consoled socket on client side it gives me this:

```
Socket {connected: false, recovered: false, receiveBuffer: Array(0), sendBuffer: Array(0), _queue: Array(0), …}
acks: {}
connected: false
flags: {}
ids: 0
io: Manager {nsps: {…}, subs: Array(1), opts: {…}, setTimeoutFn: ƒ, clearTimeoutFn: ƒ, …}
nsp: "/notifications"
receiveBuffer: []
recovered: false
sendBuffer: []
subs: (4) [ƒ, ƒ, ƒ, ƒ]
_callbacks: {$connect: Array(1), $update_notification_count: Array(1)}
_opts: {}
_queue: []
_queueSeq: 0
active: (...)
disconnected: (...)
volatile: (...)
[[Prototype]]: Emitter
```

**Client Side**

```
var socket = io("ws://127.0.0.1:1367/notifications");
socket.on('update_notification_count', function(data){
  console.log(data)
});
```

**Server Side**

```
**SocketController**

   public function actionNotify()
    {
    
          try {
        \yiicod\socketio\Broadcast::emit(CountEvent::name(), ['count' => 10]);
        echo "Notification broadcasted successfully.";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "Error broadcasting notification: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
        
    }
```

**CountEvent**

```
namespace app\events;

use yii\base\Event;
use yiicod\socketio\events\EventInterface;
use yiicod\socketio\events\EventPubInterface;

   class CountEvent implements EventInterface, EventPubInterface
    {
        /**
         * Channel name. For client side this is nsp.
         */
        public static function broadcastOn(): array
        {
            return ['notifications'];
        }
    
        /**
         * Event name
         */
        public static function name(): string
        {
            return 'update_notification_count';
        }
            
        /**
         * Emit client event
         * @param array $data
         * @return array
         */
        public function fire(array $data): array
        {
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

**Console Config**

```
'controllerMap' => [
    'socketio' => [
        'class' => \yiicod\socketio\commands\SocketIoCommand::class,
        'server'=>  '127.0.0.1:1367'
        // 'server' => 'unix:///var//run/avahi-daemon/socket',
    ],
],
```

**Common Config**

```
'broadcastEvents' => [
            'class' => \yiicod\socketio\EventManager::class,
            'nsp' => 'some_unique_key',
            // Namespaces with events folders
            'namespaces' => [
                'app\socketio',
            ]
        ],
        'broadcastDriver' => [
            'class' => \yiicod\socketio\drivers\RedisDriver::class,
            'hostname' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 6379,
        ],
```